# Urllib2 runs fine if i run the program independently but throws error when i add it to a cronjob

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.6

```
url = "www.someurl.com"

request = urllib2.Request(url,header={"User-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"})

contentString = urllib2.url(request).read()

contentFile = StringIO.StringIO(contentString)

for i in range(0,2):
    html = contentFile.readline()

print html
```

The above code runs fine from commandline but if i add it to a cron job it throws the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1186, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1161, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError:
```

I did look at some tips on the other forums and tried it but it has been of no use.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would check the following: 1. Make sure that the same python version  and python path is used in both cases. Insert a ``print sys.version; print sys.path`` at the top of the program and compare 2. Compare environment variables (``print os.environ``). Check if a ``HTTP_PROXY`` environment variable is present.

Comment: The version is the same and yes HTTP_PROXY is present.
is that the problem?

Comment: I bet it is a problem with your proxy settings. URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 3] name does not exist>

Comment: But the thing that is confusing is on the same machine how does the python script run from commandline?
Shouldn the proxy cause a problem even then?

or are the Os settings used only after i create a cron job?

Comment: Double check that the HTTP_PROXY environment variable is seen by the cronjob task. Do a ``print os.environ`` from the program and make sure that output is redirected so that you can inspect the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Before my job i add .$HOME/.profile and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

### The environment variables that were used by crontab and from the command line were different.

**I fixed this by adding */15 * * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command.**

This made the crontab to pick up enivronment variables that were specified for the system.