# Casper Python Script Failing with `/usr/bin/python` But Not `python`

Tags: python, cron, casperjs

When I run `python deamon.py`, the test suite runs properly; however, when I run it with `/usr/bin/python` it throws a warning for a `Casper.waitfor()` timeout as it apparently can't read the DOM elements.

```
// Fails:
/usr/bin/python  /path_to_deals/deals/deamon.py

// Succeeds:
python  /path_to_deals/deals/deamon.py
```

Below is the directory structure:

> deals/
>
> ```
>  deamon.py
>  test.js
> ```

`deamon.py` is the script which initiates the `casperjs` test suite in the `test.js` file.

Can any one explain why `python` works but `/usr/bin/python` does not -- and how I might fix this?

**Update from discussion:** "When I do `python deamon.py` it fails only when I put it in a Cron (where I have to specify the exact python path as well as the script path)."

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/bin/python` and `python` are referencing the same Python version?

Comment: You can see the Python version used with `which python`

Comment: yes, they are same. In fact I have only one python version i.e python2.7

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it also fail if you use `/usr/bin/env python` instead?

Comment: (Perhaps a very relevant AskUbuntu post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/372672/what-could-cause-a-script-to-fail-to-find-python-when-it-has-usr-bin-env-pyt)

Comment: @Casey yes it does, checked just now

Comment: And which OS are you on? Something Linux-flavored?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. and sublime or vim editor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57555/discussion-between-somesh-and-casey-falk).

Answer (score 2):

As [Arcege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4194/arcege) explains [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables),  *"Cron knows nothing about your shell; it is started by the system, so it has a minimal environment. If you want anything, you need to have that brought in yourself."*

Most likely, there is some variable that is set in *your* session that is being forgotten by Cron. Here are three options:

1.) You could either **set the environmental variables for a specific command** as [Nischal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126196/nischal-hp) does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827296/urllib2-runs-fine-if-i-run-the-program-independently-but-throws-error-when-i-add).

Gist:

```
* * * * * . $HOME/.profile; python /path/to/myScript.py
```

---

2.) **Set the an environmental variable for the entire Crontab** as they do [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83549/python-script-wont-write-data-when-ran-from-cron).

Gist:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * *   python /path/to/myScript.py
```

([More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use) on setting environmental variables in Cron.)

---

3.) **Set the environmental variables in the script itself**. Python's `urllib2` apparently needs the `http_proxy` variable, so if you're using that you might have a problem. You could use `os` to set it ([source](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/801093-urllib-working-differently-when-run-crontab)) or -- what might be better -- you could specify the proxy that `urllib2` should use as [ZelluX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111896/zellux) does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2) with a `ProxyHandler`.

Gist:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
```